# Hiding titles (categories) with no search results for this category (javascript search function)

Tags: javascript, html, search

When searching for questions, the categories with no search results are still visible. This code used to work before using just HTML, but we changed our code to AJAX and build HTML structure with that. This is the HTML layout when posted to page:

```
<div class="cd-faq-items" id="items">
    <ul id="${c}" class="cd-faq-group">
          <li id="${c}" class="cd-faq-title">
              <h2>${c}</h2>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="cd-faq-trigger" href="${el.id}">${el.question}</a>
                  <div class="cd-faq-content">
                     <p>${el.answer}</p>
                  </div> 
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

And the search bar html:

```
<form class="search-container">
         <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchBar()">
         <a href="#"><img class="search-icon" src="img/search-icon.png" style="color: #bbbbc7"></a>
 </form>
```

JavaScript search function:

```
        function searchBar() {
            // Declare variables
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
            var ids = ["items"];
            var count = 0
            for (var i in ids) {
                input = document.getElementById('myInput');
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

                // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query

                for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    if (li[i].className != "cd-faq-title") {
                        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            li[i].style.display = "";

                        } else {
                            li[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    if (li[i].style.display == "none") {
                        count++
                    }
                }
                if (count == (li.length - 1)) {
                    li[0].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (count < (li.length - 1)) {
                    li[0].style.display = ""
                }
                count = 0;
            }
        }
```

The page:
[image]

In the image above, the categories "Autorisatie", "EDI", "Overige", "RF" will have to be hidden. I don't know how to fix the JavaScript function, even though it's probably a simple fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using the following code:

```
var ids = [];
$("#items").find("ul.cd-faq-group").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    ids.push(id);
});
```